# How to handle inline comments within atomic rules in a Pest grammar?

Tags: grammar, peg, pest

I'm writing a pest grammar for the [fountain.io syntax](https://fountain.io/syntax/), which includes two different varieties of comment-like elements: `[[ notes ]]` set off with double-square brackets and `/* boneyard */` elements delimited with a C-style comment syntax.

I'm trying to satisfy the test cases for [Boneyards](https://github.com/nyousefi/Fountain/blob/master/FountainTests/Boneyard.fountain) and [Notes](https://github.com/nyousefi/Fountain/blob/master/FountainTests/Notes.fountain) from the reference implementation, and I'm running into problems with the internal cases.

By way of example:

```
file = { ( boneyard | note | generic_line | blank_line)+ ~ EOI }

// Basics
ws         = _{ (" " | "\t") }
start      = _{ SOI | NEWLINE }
bn_open    =  { ("[[" | "/*") }
blank_line =  { NEWLINE }
head       =  { !(NEWLINE | ws | bn_open) ~ ANY }
tail       =  { !(NEWLINE | bn_open) ~ ANY }
text       =  { bn? ~ head ~ bn? ~ (tail ~ bn?)* }

generic_line = { start ~ text ~ &NEWLINE }

// Boneyards & Notes

bn           =  { boneyard | note }
boneyard     =  { "/*" ~ boneyard_txt ~ "*/" }
boneyard_txt = @{ (boneyard | !"*/" ~ ANY)* }
note_txt     = @{ (note | !"]]" ~ ANY)* }
note         =  { "[[" ~ note_txt ~ "]]" }
```

This *almost* does what I want, but as you [can see in the pest editor](https://pest.rs/?g=N4Ig5gTghgtjURALhAMwJYBsCmACAvLsLgBS4BGA9gHbYCeCAJrgD67WUAuebY2tEdAGMA%2BpnS1WFTFGoBrMROwBKANS4AfrgCiAeQCSuAL4AdamYD0F3ACEoAZ2H2zAd3u4Pnz4RHESJkFwAqQCTE04A5WMze04ETi8PH2IAZQMpADltAHUAGX0s6OpyahFKAAd%2BL0IiUgCAbXrgtgCLACpIovIZeUVJGuIsvILtIoALbChmRIIPYgBCEiH8wrY3KRKyyuoorQBBDIBNIrisGdnaxeWRjdKK-l3cA%2BPTam4ADwSZgYpqAH5NLgJlNASUAVoSKdMKD-so2kUzHwBMI%2BnhCMRYvFAR8EloAGTXQqvSzWGw0ehMdx43AZLjYZzmYrUc7VOYUckMCDMNgcbhdDlMRI-VodQJaKi0TmMEScT6AgJtCzBV4SilcmVywgAAT8qqlUnmCqVYqeRzhRV52A1X28uB1pEtBoCAF1ncF9mb4a9HSzhSBGu72HTrfKQK7lSAADQgCTlACunGQID2uHEtAAdGYzI0U5b0%2BHGY0ACpjdDuNN4ezlWQMjwwOOYTjoco4VNKez5t2Mktl3C92S4RoSbgQahQTCuoPcTPUEBGIA#editor), it splits each text character and makes the output very noisy:

```
- file
  - generic_line > text
    - head: "A"
    - tail: " "
    - tail: "l"
    - tail: "i"
    - tail: "n"
    - tail: "e"
    - tail: "."
  - blank_line: "\n"
  - blank_line: "\n"
  - note > note_txt: "A note."
  - blank_line: "\n"
  - blank_line: "\n"
  - note > note_txt: "This note spans\n  multiple lines."
  - blank_line: "\n"
  - generic_line > text
    - head: "T"
    - tail: "h"
    - tail: "i"
    - tail: "s"
    - tail: " "
    - tail: "i"
    - tail: "s"
    - tail: " "
    - tail: "a"
    - tail: "n"
    - tail: " "
    - bn > note > note_txt: "internal"
    - tail: " "
    - tail: "n"
    - tail: "o"
    - tail: "t"
    - tail: "e"
    - tail: "."
  - blank_line: "\n"
  - EOI: ""
```

If I make the `text` rule atomic, `text =  @{ bn? ~ head ~ bn? ~ (tail ~ bn?)* }` then the results are cleaner and more readable, closer to how I'd like to actually use them:

```
- file
  - generic_line > text: "A line."
  - blank_line: "\n"
  - blank_line: "\n"
  - note > note_txt: "A note."
  - blank_line: "\n"
  - blank_line: "\n"
  - note > note_txt: "This note spans\n  multiple lines."
  - blank_line: "\n"
  - generic_line > text: "This is an [[internal]] note."
  - blank_line: "\n"
  - EOI: ""
```

But sadly that causes the `[[ internal ]]` notes and boneyards to be miscategorized as generic text lines. I also tried making `text`  a compound-atomic (`$`) rule, but that didn't make any difference from a non-atomic rule in this case.

Does anyone have any suggestions here? Do I have any options besides taking the character-by-character output and concatenating them all in application code?

Answer (score 0):

After a few attempts, I think I've got an result that's pretty close to what I wanted. This grammar...

```
file = { (boneyard | note | generic_line | blank_line)+ ~ EOI }

// Basics
ws            = _{ (" " | "\t") }
start         = _{ SOI | NEWLINE }
bn_open       =  { ("[[" | "/*") }
blank_line    =  { NEWLINE }
text_fragment =  { (!(NEWLINE | bn_open) ~ ANY)+ }
text          = _{ (bn | text_fragment)+ }

generic_line = _{ start ~ text ~ &NEWLINE }

// Boneyards & Notes

bn           = _{ boneyard | note }
boneyard     = _{ "/*" ~ boneyard_txt ~ "*/" }
boneyard_txt = @{ (boneyard | !"*/" ~ ANY)* }
note_txt     = @{ (note | !"]]" ~ ANY)* }
note         = _{ "[[" ~ note_txt ~ "]]" }
```

Produces output like...

```
- file
  - text_fragment: "A line."
  - blank_line: "\n"
  - note_txt: "A note."
  - blank_line: "\n"
  - note_txt: "This line spans\n  multiple lines."
  - blank_line: "\n"
  - text_fragment: "This is an "
  - note_txt: "internal"
  - text_fragment: " note."
  - blank_line: "\n"
  - EOI: ""
```

The trick here is making `text` into a container that dispatches between either `text_fragment` or `boneyard/notes`comment types. So `text_fragment` becomes the atomic rule, but if we make it silent by prefixing with _, then the output is reasonably clean.

[Pest editor link](https://pest.rs/?g=N4Ig5gTghgtjURALhAMwJYBsCmACAvLsLgBS4BGA9gHbYCeCAJrgD67WUAuebY2tEdAGMA%2BpnS1WFTFGoBrMROwBKANS4AfrgCiAeQCSuAL4AdamYD0F3ACEoAZ2H2zAd3u4Pnz4RHESJkFwAqQCTE04A5WMze04ETi8PH2IAZQMpADltAHUAGX0s6OpyahFKAAd%2BL0IiUgCAbXrgtgCLACpIovIZeUVJGuIsvILtIu4AD04RVGgwGH4EglqSAEISIfzCthKyyuoorQBBDIBNNWMg6gnFxJrfUhKpa%2BnZ%2Bavz03NqPgFhPrxkrhYvFNLhrqCAGQbEZFSzWGw0ehMdwQ3AZLjYZxfR6JW4ee5UWgMCDMNgcbhdRHE5jVfHEVodQJaQlIkkiTiTUEBNoWYKfFnU9mcwgAAT8AqYUhW3N5TNwxzObSK5OwQpuSVwYtIKqlAQAunrgkdTsolZ8dbiNbh7g0mnKVWquSADXyQAAaEAScoAV04yBAh1w4loADozGZGoGVSGXV9GgAVAAW6Hcwbw9nKsixHhg3swnHQ5RwQaU9hjhq%2BSZTuGrslwjQk3Ag1CgmAN7AxYeoICMQA#editor)